# Null Pointer Exception when setting new text to text view

Tags: android

I am trying to run an AndroidApp on my phone. I am able to show my welcome fragment, moreover I can trigger the log-message. Unfortunately I am getting a null pointer exception if I want to change the text value from 'welcome' to 'Neuer Text'. What went wrong? I am quite new to android development.

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
        Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Log.d("JobaApp", "Logtext"); // see LogCat
        TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.welcome_text);
        text1.setText("NeuerText");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the view of the TextView from the Button? I take it the Button does not contain the TextView, therefor you will get a NullException.

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace of the exception. Wild guess: `text1` is `null`, no such view `R.id.welcome_text` exists.

Comment: Is the view that is being clicked the textview that you are trying to change?

Answer (score 2):

In the `onClick()`, `v` is the view item that was clicked, e.g. the button, not the view that is inflated in `onCreateView()`.

You should use `getView()`:

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
        Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Log.d("JobaApp", "Logtext"); // see LogCat
        switch (v.getId) {
        case R.id.button1:
            TextView text1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.welcome_text);
            text1.setText("NeuerText");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you don't want that action taking place for every button you may want to consider using a `switch` statement in your `onClick()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cant get the TextView from the button's onClick passed parameter ("View v"), since this is the actual button's view.

You should do something like:

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
View view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
        Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Log.d("JobaApp", "Logtext"); // see LogCat
        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.welcome_text);
        text1.setText("NewerText"); //Also fixed typo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `OnClick(View v)` , v is the button that you are clicking on. The TextView does not belong to Button, it belongs to `R.layout.fragment_welcome`. So you find and initialize the TextView inside `onCreateView()` of the fragment, and then use it inside onClick();
Some what like this:

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
TextView tv;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
        Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.welcome_text);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Log.d("JobaApp", "Logtext"); // see LogCat

        tv.setText("NeuerText");
    }
}
```